# How to merge combine or flatten multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that is conference rooms with corresponding reservations. The conference rooms are repeating, but the corresponding reservations will be different, and I want no repeating conference rooms and to merge all the reservations for each conference room.

```
This is what I have:
['conference room one', ['reservation 2', 'reservation 1', 'reservation 3']]
['conference room two', ['reservation 7', 'reservation 5', 'reservation 6']]
['conference room two', ['reservation 10', 'reservation 11', 'reservation 12']]
['conference room one', ['reservation 9', 'reservation 8', 'reservation 15']]
['conference room one', ['reservation 17', 'reservation 14', 'reservation 13']]


This is what I want:
['conference room one', ['reservation 2', 'reservation 1', 'reservation 3', 'reservation 9', 'reservation 8', 'reservation 15', 'reservation 17', 'reservation 14', 'reservation 13']]
['conference room two', ['reservation 7', 'reservation 5', 'reservation 6', 'reservation 10', 'reservation 11', 'reservation 12']]
```

(deleted a screenshot that was here because it was irrelevant and distracting)

Comment: how do you store these arrays? In object, in variables, in other array?

Comment: It's an object. I just added a screenshot above. Not sure if my simplified illustration is accurate.

Comment: Those objects in image don't match what is shown in question code. Always provide a [mcve] to start with

Comment: @Ele I'm trying this out in my code. I will let you know soon.

Comment: @charlietfl not exactly, but aren't they similar in structure? Or am I way off?

Comment: Yes...enough that answers provided so far  will break with real data because they were derived from your pseudo data

Comment: @amrender singh I'm trying to apply your code to my situation. Can you take a look at my actual object structure above in the screenshot? I get how it's supposed to work but I'm not able to access the "events" for each [curr[0]].

Comment: @ele trying to figure out how to access "events" with the actual structure shown in the screenshot above. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()`, to create a map and group all the values, After that simply use `Object.values()` to get array of all the values.

Try the following:

```js
var arr = [['conference room one', ['reservation 2', 'reservation 1', 'reservation 3']],
['conference room two', ['reservation 7', 'reservation 5', 'reservation 6']],
['conference room two', ['reservation 10', 'reservation 11', 'reservation 12']],
['conference room one', ['reservation 9', 'reservation 8', 'reservation 15']],
['conference room one', ['reservation 17', 'reservation 14', 'reservation 13']]];

var result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a,curr)=>{
  if(!a[curr[0]]){ // if the room is not present in map than add it.
    a[curr[0]] = curr;
  } else{ // if room exist than simply concat the reservations array of map and current element
      a[curr[0]][1] = a[curr[0]][1].concat(curr[1]);
  }
  return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back on this. I ended up changing some of my code and how I'm building my array to work better with this. I chose this one as the accepted answer because it was a little easier for me to understand and learn about how to use reduce. Now I'm a big fan of reduce. Hope it's okay to put this link to a medium article which I found very educational and clearly explained: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/reduce-f47a7da511a9 Thank you very much for these answers. It worked and I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using the function `reduce` to group the conferences and its reservations and the function `Object.values` to extract the grouped values.

```js
let array = [['conference room one', ['reservation 2', 'reservation 1', 'reservation 3']],['conference room two', ['reservation 7', 'reservation 5', 'reservation 6']],['conference room two', ['reservation 10', 'reservation 11', 'reservation 12']],['conference room one', ['reservation 9', 'reservation 8', 'reservation 15']],['conference room one', ['reservation 17', 'reservation 14', 'reservation 13']]],
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, [conference, reservations]) => {
      (a[conference] || (a[conference] = [conference, []]))[1].push(...reservations);
      return a;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```